# Checkbox button in my input-group-prepend

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a way to make a "checkbox button" in "input-group-prepend" and make it look like it fits there perfectly?
tried:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checked
  </label>
</div>
```

but it wont fit as nice as:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
```

Some more context i guess:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">

          <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
              <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checked
            </label>
          </div>

        </div>
        <input value="<?php echo($this->session->userdata('fname')) ?>" name="fname" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="fname">
      </div>
```

edit, some screenshots:

What i want:

[image: What i want]

What i get:

[image: what i get]

Comment: Please bring a JSFiddle when experiencing this kind of problem. Also what do you mean by "won't fit nicely" ?

Comment: I'll edit in some screenshots, gimme a sec

Comment: Found a solution. *writing it*

Comment: Yea man, tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working solution :

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <!-- merged .input-group-prepend and .btn-group-toggle divs -->
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checked
    </label>
  </div>
  <input value="foo" name="fname" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="fname">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm56Z/s51y0fq9/)